# Correct use of bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass a value from one html template to another. I have an API which identifies the username and his role, and I want to send the username value. Per example, this is my code from a file called `"payment-component.js"`:

```
(function(){
     'use strict';
    var payments = {
        templateUrl: './app/component-pay.html',
        controller: payCtrl
    };

    angular
    .module('payApp')
    .component('payThis', payments);
    payCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];
    function payCtrl($scope){

    function users (){
        //$scope.userName;
        $http.get('api/UserRoleUser?sendUserValue=true')
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.thisUser = data.data.Response;            

        });
     }

}

})();
```

HTML view:

```
<div class="title">
   <h3><strong>Welcome, {{thisUser}}!</strong></h3>
</div>
```

I need to pass `thisUser` to another file but is not working. The other documents are `detail-component.js`:

```
(function(){
     'use strict';
    var home = {
        templateUrl: './app/component/detail-component/detail.html',
        controller: homeCtrl
    };

    angular
    .module('payApp')
    .component('home', home);

    function homeCtrl(){

        var home = this;
    }

    })();
```

And it html view (`detail.html`):

```
<div class="title">
  <h3><strong>This is your detail, {{userName}}!</strong></h3>
</div>
```

I'd read a little bit, and I know I have to bind the data from one side to another, but I don't know how to do that. I'm still learning...

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Use a service to share data across various parts of the app

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368222/angularjs-transfer-data-between-pages/34368875#34368875

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $rootScope if component is parent child 
So in you **payment-component.js**

```
$scope.thisUser = data.data.Response;
```

change to

```
$rootScope.thisUser = data.data.Response;
```

you need to add $rootScope in payCtrl like this

```
payCtrl.$inject = ["$scope","$rootScope"];
```

Comment: Thanx. And, on the homeCtrl i just pass the value `{{userName}}`? or have also to declare $scope/$rootScope?

Comment: Thanx again. I've found how to use it very well :)

Answer (score 0):

Add 'payApp' module as dependency to 'pageoApp' module and get the 'thisUser' using a factory method (say getuser)  instead of using controller.
Add this getuser as dependency to your homeCtrl and try to access 'thisUser'