# Passing data from one page to another in angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

How do I pass data from one page to another in angular js?
I have heard about using something as services but I am not sure how to use it!
Given below is the functionality I want to execute!
On page 1:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="mycontrl">
  <label for="singleSelect"> Select Date </label><br>
  <select nAMe="singleSelect" ng-model="dateSelect">
    <option value="2/01/2015">2nd Jan</option>
    <option value="3/01/2015">3rd Jan</option>  
  </select>
  <br>
  Selected date = {{dateSelect}}
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <label for="singleSelect"> Select time </label><br>
  <select nAMe="singleSelect" ng-model="timeSelect">
    <option value="9/10">9AM-10AM</option>
    <option value="10/11">10AM-11AM</option>
    <option value="11/12">11AM-12PM</option>
    <option value="12/13">12PM-1PM</option>
    <option value="13/14">1PM-2PM</option>
  </select>
  <button ng-click="check()">Check!</button>
  <br>
  Selected Time = {{timeSelect}}
  <br/><br/>
```

User selects time and date and that is used to make call to the db and results are stored in a variable array!
Page 1 controller:

```
var config= {
  params: { 
    time: times,
    date:dates
  }
};

$http.get('/era',config).success(function(response) {
  console.log("I got the data I requested");
  $scope.therapist_list = response;
});
```

Now how do I send this variable `$scope.therapist_list` which is an array to next page which will be having a different controller and also if services is use how do define it in my application.js file

application.js:

```
var firstpage=angular.module('firstpage', []);
var secondpage=angular.module('secondpage', []);
```

Comment: Search for ngRoute. Basicly you gonna change your route after the successfull GET. With that routeChange you can add parameters, like your list.

Comment: Some Angular services docs/tutorials:  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services, http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_services.htm

Comment: Also, You dont really want to create a module per page.

Comment: RootScope remains as it is after changing controllers.. So set in $rootScope and access it in any child controller.

Comment: this is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408790/angularjs-passing-data-between-pages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To save the data that you want to transfer to another `$scope` or saved during the routing, you can use the services (`Service`). Since the `service` is a `singleton`, you can use it to store and share data.

Look at the example of [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/5m0hwbe1/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("ExampleOneController", function($scope, NewsService) {
  $scope.news = NewsService.news;
});
myApp.controller("ExampleTwoController", function($scope,NewsService) {
  $scope.news = NewsService.news;
});

myApp.service("NewsService", function() {
  return {
    news: [{theme:"This is one new"}, {theme:"This is two new"}, {theme:"This is three new"}]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleOneController">
    <h2>
  ExampleOneController
  </h2>
    <div ng-repeat="n in news">
      <textarea ng-model="n.theme"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleTwoController">
    <h2>
  ExampleTwoController
  </h2>
  <div ng-repeat="n in news">
      <div>{{n.theme}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**UPDATED**

Showing using variable in different controller [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/5m0hwbe1/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("ExampleOneController", function($scope, NewsService) {
  $scope.newVar = {
    val: ""
  };
  NewsService.newVar = $scope.newVar;
  $scope.news = NewsService.news;
});
myApp.controller("ExampleTwoController", function($scope, NewsService) {
  $scope.anotherVar = NewsService.newVar;
  $scope.news = NewsService.news;
});

myApp.service("NewsService", function() {
  return {
    news: [{
      theme: "This is one new"
    }, {
      theme: "This is two new"
    }, {
      theme: "This is three new"
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleOneController">
    <h2>
  ExampleOneController
  </h2>
    <div ng-repeat="n in news">
      <textarea ng-model="n.theme"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input ng-model="newVar.val">
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleTwoController">
    <h2>
  ExampleTwoController
  </h2>
    <div ng-repeat="n in news">
      <div>{{n.theme}}</div>
    </div>
    <pre>newVar from ExampleOneController {{anotherVar.val}}</pre>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah but how do I declare a variable value in controller 1 and use it in controller 2?

Answer (score 0):

OK,
you write a another module ewith factory service e.g.

```
angular
    .module('dataApp')
    .factory('dataService', factory);

factory.$inject = ['$http', '$rootScope', '$q', '$log'];

function factory($http, $rootScope,$q,$log) {
    var service = {
        list: getList
    };
    service.therapist_list = null;
    return service;


    function getList() {
        var config= {
            params: { 
                time: times,
                date:dates
            }
        };

        $http.get('/era',config).success(function(response) {
        console.log("I got the data I requested");
        $scope.therapist_list = response;

        });

        $log.debug("get Students service");
        $http.get('/era',config).then(function successCallback(response) {
            service.therapist_list = response.data;
            $log.debug(response.data);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            $log.debug("error" + response);
        });
    }
}
```

Add this module as dependencies to your both page apps like

```
var firstpage=angular.module('firstpage', [dataApp]);
var secondpage=angular.module('secondpage', [dataApp]);
```

and then in your controller consume that service

```
.controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'dataService', function ($scope, dataService) {
}]);
```