# How to show data one page to other in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need some help from you guys I am new in AngularJs, I have code  there  is too long code thats why I upload doc file, please check it below link, Using the code snippet below I'm authenticating email, password. The customerlogin() method returns some JSON data which I want to show in the next page. In other words I want to pass the data returned from `customerlogin()` to `then()` and then pass it to /customerprofil

Please help, my boss tell me follow this code but how to transfer data other page and show using angular js, my code is different you show dublicats

[Code is there](http://geomap.sharphit.com/Customerlogin.docx)

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-app="agfullstackApp.customerprofile">
    <form action="">
        <div class="form-group" ng-controller="customerprofileComponent">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputDefault">{{full_name}}</label>
        </div>
```

Comment: you can see this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408790/angularjs-passing-data-between-pages

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular service to share the data between pages. But the data will be lost if you re-fresh the page. Following is an example using service.

```
angular.module('myServiceModule',[])
.service('myService', function() {
    var savedData = {}
    this.setData  = function(data) {
        savedData = data;
    }
    this.getData = function() {
        return savedData;
    }
});
```

Then set data from controller 1.

```
app.controller('View1Ctrl', ['myService', function(myService) {
    myService.setData("some data from view 1")  ;
}]);
```

To get the data from controller 2.

```
app.controller('View2Ctrl', ['myService', function(myService) {
    console.log(myService.getData());
}]);
```

If you want your data available even after page refresh, you need to use localStorage. https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage 
(It is better to use angular-local-storage module as it support cookie fallback in case of unsupported browsers or storage capacity problems)